# How to write multiple lines of code in Python as a single line?

Tags: python, multiline

The app I am using doesn't allow new lines, so for this example I need my code to be written as a single line.

I tried the semicolon character but I don't know how to handle the `for loops`. Do I have to put a space after semicolon, or can I just piece statements without space? For the for loop, should I use a single space, 4 space, or just a tab? I am not sure if the app preserves tabs but the new lines become a single space.

So I need to do this:

```
statement1;statement2;forloop:;for_loop_statement1;statement3
```

EDIT: Actual code:

```
nums = [substring.split(',') for substring in s.split()]
for row in nums:
    row[1] = '0'
return ' '.join(','.join(row) for row in nums)
```

Comment: Here's [something](http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/python/oneline/) to check out. Basically it's a bunch of tricks to rewrite your code in a one liner way. Also out of curiosity what's the program?

Comment: Thanks, it's just a (badly-designed) internal DCC app.

Comment: I don't think this question has a general answer - it would be better if you could post the code you want to transform to a one-liner.

Comment: Ok posted the actual code.

Comment: Shouldn't it be a `def` statement there?

Comment: In the app I am using, the whole code sort of works as a function, you can replace it with print but the app requires you to return something in your code. Also the code fails before it even gets to that. I am still trying to get the for loop statement working. I didn't use return yet.

Comment: Why do you want to turn readable code into an unparseable on-line mess?

Comment: I told in the description, that's what the app requires. As long as it works, I don't care tbh since this code will likely never be revisited, it's a one off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a better way of solving the problem (using `or` and `__setitem__` to change the content of `row`). To change which item to substitute, just change the `1` in `row.__setitem__(1, '0')` to whatever index you'd like.

```
def foo(s):
    nums = [substring.split(',') for substring in s.split()];return ' '.join(','.join(row.__setitem__(1, '0') or row) for row in nums)

print foo('a,b,c d,e,f, g,h,i')
```

**Output:**

```
a,0,c d,0,f, g,0,i
```

This works since `__setitem__` works in-place, and hence always returns `None`. Since the first statement in `row.__setitem__(1, '0') or row` is `None`, the result of the expression after `or` is yielded (i.e. `row`, which is what we want).

Comment: Wow thanks, it works beautifully. Nice trick removing the standalone loop :)

Comment: Also since the for loop is changed, do you know how to change the code so I can do the same for replacing the first or the third element instead of 2? I tried changing row[1] but it inserts 0 not replaces.

Comment: This is the row which is joined: `[row[0], '0'] + row[2:]`. So if you want to change the first item, you would have to do `['0'] + row[1:]`, and to change the third: `row[:2] + ['0'] + row[3:]`

Comment: Thanks alot Steinar, it works. I wouldn't have guessed that syntax.

Comment: @JoanVenge I've updated the answer with a better solution, have a look. It is more flexible than the first solution.

Comment: Thanks alot, tried it and it works, and easier to understand. Out of curiosity, do you have to use the setitem method with underscores? Is there a "friendlier" version? I thought those methods were secret.

Comment: `a.__setitem__(1, '0')` is the hard way of saying `a[1] = '0'`, but you can't do assignments inside expressions in Python, hence this workaround. You are correct that these methods are rarely used, but sometimes you need to apply some hacks in order to solve some problems :)

Comment: Thanks alot that makes sense. Is this a limitation of expressions or by design? Do you know if this will be addressed? Just curious because like you said it works, and that's all that matters :)

Comment: This is by design, see (last paragraph) [this link](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions): `Note that in Python, unlike C, assignment cannot occur inside expressions. C programmers may grumble about this, but it avoids a common class of problems encountered in C programs: typing = in an expression when == was intended.`

Answer (score 0):

from my terminal commandline:

```
>>> x=1;y=2
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
>>> for i in range(1,5):print(i);pass
... 
1
2
3
4
>>>
```

Comment: Doesn't work: `for i in range(10):print(i);pass;print('hey');` outputs `1\nhey\n2\nhey...`, (`statement3` gets evaluated in the loop)

Comment: Thanks so I shouldn't use ; after the for loop? I didn't think of that. Will try it now.

Comment: As plg pointed out the problem is you can't end the for loop, at least i couldn't figure out how. Everything after `:` is part of the forloop then.

Comment: Oh, and i did not get an invalid syntax in the standard Python 2.7.6 interactive console.

Comment: Sorry I meant the app I am using returns this error saying something is wrong. The syntax is fine but it's because of not being able to format the code due to the 1 line restriction.

Comment: With `for i in range(10):print(i);pass;print('hey');`, `statement3` is expected to be evaluated in the loop, because `pass` does nothing, and from the python documentation on "Compound statements": `the semicolon binds tighter than the colon`, meaning that all commands joined with semicolons are inside the for loop.  As for ending the loop, just use a newline!  
However, this answer does not answer the question, because it doesn't seem to be possible to put a for-loop and a statement after (outside) of the for-loop on the same line using this style.